# how can i save player name and score in my java game?

Tags: java, android, save, indexoutofboundsexception

i am making my first android game.i want to save the user name and score to a file and read it later.i am trying to use arraylist to store 5 user objects.I don't know how to write efficiently to the file and read it back and store in arraylist. if you know another beter way please tell me.
here is the method I am using to write.

```
public static void save(FileIO file) {
    preferences = file.getSharedPref();
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        editor.putString("username"+String.valueOf(i), User.userList.get(i).userName);
        editor.putInt("userscore"+String.valueOf(i), User.userList.get(i).highScore);
        }
    editor.commit();
}
```

And this is the method I am using to read.

```
public static void read(FileIO file) {
    preferences = file.getSharedPref();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        User.userList.get(i).userName=preferences.getString("username"+String.valueOf(i), "abc");
        User.userList.get(i).highScore=preferences.getInt("userscore"+String.valueOf(i), 0);
    }

}
```

And this is the loop I am trying to display my highscore.
`for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                     g.drawString(String.valueOf(i+1)+"."+String.valueOf(User.userList.get(i).userName), 100, y, paint);
                    g.drawString(String.valueOf(User.userList.get(i).highScore),150, y, paint2);
                    y+=80;
        }`

i am getting indexoutofbounds exception

Comment: Please provided more detailed information on a concrete problem. Also set proper tags for programming language and platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wish to store values:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Your_Activity.this);

Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("username", "<username goes here>");
editor.putInt("score", <the score goes here>);
editor.commit();   // Do not forget this to actually store the values
```

When you wish to read these values later:

```
String gameUsername = sp.getString("username", "default");
int gameScore = sp.getInt("score", 0);
```

"username" and "score" are the keys for their respected values.

SharedPreferences is the simplest way that comes to mind when storing values.
Hope it helps. 
~Cheers.

Comment: Some coding errors I have spotted at a first glance:
- In the read() method, you have 
'for(int i=0;i<0;i++)'
it never enters the loop.
- When you attempt to display your score use 
'for(int i=0;i<User.userList.size();i++)'

Comment: I have corrected that silly mistake of mine.now I am getting indexoutofbounds error in read() method

Comment: Have you changed the display and reading loops to `for(int i=0;i<User.userList.size();i++)` ?
If your using Eclipse IDE try putting a breakpoint at the read() method and use the debugger to see step by step what goes wrong.

Comment: it worked,but I think it is not saving and reading the values properly.i get blank scores screen.i tried to change the condition in for loop of both methods to the one you suggested.Force close is gone but it is not saving and reading the values now.

Comment: Why are you using FileIO file? Try omitting that and use SharedPreferences as stated in my answer, I believe it will work.

Comment: its just a class i created.my SharedPreferences are working fine as i am using similar method to store my seetings state.

Comment: Thank you for your help.it works now.The problem i had was my arraylist was empty

Comment: @koksroks is sharedpreference work like database when you close the app can you still access your previous data stored in sharedpreference?